# Como fazer a borda da imagem abaixo?

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de fazer uma borda como a da imagem abaixo, que sai da imagem e que esta embaixo do texto Design Your Ring.
 [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloque o código fonte que vc já fez.

Comment: Isso provavelmente é um `border-bottom` no div que tem o texto Design Your Ring

Comment: Um `border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(190,190,190,.5);` ou uma cor parecida

Answer (score 1):

```css
   *  {
 margin: 0px;
}

div {
 height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: gray;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

h1 {
 text-align: right;
}

hr {
 float: left;
 width: 300px;
    color: rgba(150,140,190,.5);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>


</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>Foto Aqui</div>
 <h1>Teste</h1><br>
<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!!